# Django ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'myuser'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I need to use my usernames to `panel/profile/<username>` address. So what I did in `models` is:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

And in  `urls.py` I have these paths:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('panel', views.home, name='panel'),

    path('panel/register', views.registerPage, name='register'),
    path('panel/login', views.loginPage, name='login'),
    path('panel/logout', views.logoutPage, name='logout'),

    path('dashboard', views.userProfile, name='dashboard'),
    path('dashboard/settings/edit-profile', views.userSettings, name='settings'),

    path('panel/profile/<str:username>', views.profile, name='profile'),
]
```

and in this way there is no problem:

```
>>> customer=Customer.objects.get(user_id=118)
>>> customer.user.username
'myuser'
```

But in `views.py` I need to grab username as a part of URL like that:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['admins'])
def profile(request, username):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(user=username)
    print(type(customer), customer)
```

But I have this error:

```
ValueError at /panel/profile/myuser
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'myuser'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use span relation to get the `Customer` instance

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['admins'])
def profile(request, username):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(user__username=username)
    print(type(customer), customer)
```

Comment: Thank you it is solved. But why do we get this error?